# How can i make on Selected index changed for html backdrop?

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio, web

I am using vb.net with asp controls but i want to use html and css in the project.
i made a backdrop list using html in the asp content and it is visible in the web form but i want to access it using vb.net code behind as we acces the dropdownlist by using dropdownlist.Selectedindexchanged.

this is the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello sami</h1>
        <form action="">
            <select name="backdrop" id="background" runat="server">
                <option value="random">Random</option>
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>
                <option value="reset">Reset</option>

            </select><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'd recommend updating to an `<asp:DropDownList>` with `AutoPostBack = True`, but you can use your html select as well, just needs an extra little bit of JS.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <select name="backdrop" id="background" runat="server" onchange="javascript:form1.submit();">
            <option value="random">Random</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="reset">Reset</option>
        </select>

        <asp:Label ID="lblOutputValue" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
```

```
Protected Sub background_ServerChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles background.ServerChange
    Dim selectedValue As String = Me.background.Value
    Dim selectedIndex As Integer = Me.background.SelectedIndex
    Me.lblOutputValue.Text = selectedValue
End Sub
```

Update for DropdownList:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="background" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Value="Random" Text="Random" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="Red" Text="Red" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="Green" Text="Green" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="Reset" Text="Reset" />
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="lblOutputValue" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
```

```
Protected Sub background_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles background.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim selectedValue As String = Me.background.SelectedValue
    Dim selectedIndex As Integer = Me.background.SelectedIndex
    Me.lblOutputValue.Text = selectedValue
End Sub
```

Comment: i am using dropwdownlist from asp but my software is slow a bit for example if i press a button to view some controls it takes a bit of time on server so i need it to be faster i do not know if using html is better or not but i want to try.

Comment: where is the submit() method call also?

Comment: @symix world. what is your current problem? I think the answer is very good. If the dropdownlist only contains 4 items, I think it may not be too low.

Comment: where is the submit() method call also:    You only need this part ````onchange="javascript:form1.submit();"```` if you're using the html ````<select>````. If you're using the ````<asp:DropDownList> with AutoPostBack = True```` then you don't need that part as ASP handles all the JS code.

Comment: If your goal is simply to take the selected text from the drop down list and display it to the user in some other means (like a label or tag on the page), you can accomplish that with JavaScript / jQuery without the need to PostBack your page (which as you said, takes a lot of time).